# Best way to add an specific char after and before another char in a SQL Server variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Considering this variable

```sql
declare @disks nvarchar (500)

set @disks = 'C:\,F:\,E:\,K:\,Y:\'
```

What is the best way to transform this variable to this desired output?

The output desired is:

```
'C:\','F:\','E:\','K:\','Y:\'
```

Comment: select ''''+replace(@disks,',',''',''')+''''

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the use-case, but if you stored this in a resultset/some type of temptable, you'd be able to select them all and aggregate for whatever output you wanted. SQL and storing a lot of data as a single string tend not to mix.

Comment: thanks John Cappelletti

Comment: What is `'C:\','F:\','E:\','K:\','Y:\'`? Is this just another `nvarchar` or are you looking for something like [How to implement array-like functionality in SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/implement-array-like-functionality-sql-server/)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this goal is to use the ASCII encoding:

```
SELECT CHAR(39)+'C:\'+CHAR(39)+', '+CHAR(39)+'F:\'+CHAR(39)+', '+CHAR(39)+'E:\'+CHAR(39)
```